# Automatically generated velocity template file from a given html file

Tags: automation, velocity, templating-engine

Is there a way to automatically generate Velocity Template file from a given reference implementation html file.

Right now I have to update my velocity template manually whenever there are changes in html or ts files.

Is there are way to automate this process?

Comment: Can you add example of your code to make question clear?

Answer (score 0):

The most obvious way of achieving this, assuming that most of the times HTML changes appear on lines which don't contain VTL, is to rely on a versioning system like git.

1. Let's say that your templatized files are under the `master` branch.
2. Create a new `reference` branch, overwrite the templatized files with the reference ones, and commit the result.
3. Since the goal is to merge `reference` towards `master`, to be able to avoid chekky-picking so as to ease the merging process, I would do a first merge from `reference` to `master`, commit it, then overwrite the result of the merge with the templatized files and commit again. The result of the operation leaves the files unchanged, but git will consider the `reference` branch as being already merged.
4. Whenever new changes in the reference branch appear, you just have to commit them in the `reference` branch and ask git to merge them towards `master`. From times to times, youll have to manually handle some conflicts.

I'm not detailing here git usage, but there are [plenty of good tutorials](https://gist.github.com/jaseemabid/1321592) online.